# Adding user to local user group with python

Tags: python, windows, automation

I am trying to add users to the local user group with win32 module. It says that the user does not exist although I am able to add the same user manually. Why is this not working from python?

def add_user(user, group):
user = input("Enter username: ")
win32net.NetLocalGroupAddMembers(None, group, 3, [user])

I run it like add_user("Sree","Users") and I get the error 'A member could not be added to or removed from the local group because the member does not exist. ' When I try manually, the same user gets added.

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far

Comment: def add_user(user, group):                                                                              
       user = input("Enter username: ")                                                      
       win32net.NetLocalGroupAddMembers(None, group, 3, [user])                                                                                                             I run it like add_user("Sree","Users") and I get the error 'A member could not be added to or removed from the local group because the member does not exist. '   When I try manually, the same user gets added.

Comment: please put that in the post as an edit,

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a list of dictionaries instead of a list of strings.
See [pywin32 doc](https://mhammond.github.io/pywin32/win32net__NetLocalGroupAddMembers_meth.html)

Try this:

```
win32net.NetLocalGroupAddMembers(None, group, 3, [{'domainandname': f'{domain}\\{user}'}])
```